# Apt-get package depends on itself (filebeat)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

I have multiple servers with Ubuntu 14.04 and installed filebeat on every machine except one, and I can't figure out how to fix it actually. but the package depends on it self.

I tried to install filebeat with the docs side by side 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/current/setup-repositories.html

I have run `apt-get clean` I removed the PGP key, i remove the entry from sources.list with `apt-get update` etc and even tried a reboot.

But I keep getting the following message

```
sudo apt-get install filebeat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package filebeat is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'filebeat' has no installation candidate
```

When running `apt-cache depends|rdepends` I get the dependency result which is strange.

```
apt-cache depends filebeat
<filebeat>
apt-cache rdepends filebeat
<filebeat>
```

So it seems that the package depends on itself.

The server is not running in production and can be rebuild. But I just want to know what happend here and how to solve it.

Comment: If you removed the source that provides this package, why would you expect to then be able to install it?

Comment: And added them back again of course

Comment: Looks like the upstream source is bogus.. when I try opening https://packages.elastic.co/beats/apt, I get an unformatted xml response saying something about it not existing.  What does apt-cache show filebeat say?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/751589/apt-get-package-depends-on-itself-filebeat I posted the results here